# LINQ - Left Outer Join with multiple parameters in Where clause

Tags: sql, linq, llblgenpro

How can I do this SQL query in LINQ:

```
select * from chat c
left outer join lead s on c.key = s.id
where (typeId = 5 AND c.key = @clientId) OR (c.typeId = 4 AND s.clientId = @clientId)
```

Or this SQL query -- Same, same

```
select * from chat c
where (typeId = 5 AND c.key = @clientId) OR (typeId = 4 AND c.key in (select id from lead where clientId = @clientId))
```

What I have:

```
var chatter = (from chat in linq.Chat
             join lead in linq.Lead
                on chat.key equals lead.Id.ToString() into clientLeads
                from cl in clientLeads.Where(l => l.clientId == clientId).DefaultIfEmpty()
            where (chat.typeId == 5 && chat.key == clientId.ToString()) ||
                (chat.typeId == 4 && chat.key == cl.Id.ToString())
                select chat).WithPath(prefetchPath).OrderByDescending(c => c.CreatedDate);
```

The above LINQ query doesn't yeild any results from the latter WHERE clause, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I translated the second query to linq:

```
var leadIds = linq.Lead.Where(l => l.clientId == clientId.ToString()).Select(l => l.id);
var chatter = from chat in linq.Chat
              where (chat.typeId == 5 && chat.key == clientId.ToString()) ||
                    (chat.typeId == 4 && leadIds.Contains(chat.key));
```

Comment: Man, I actually tried something very close but I must have messed it up! This works!